# Regex for multiple IPs and ranges and subnets for NPS

Tags: regex, windows-server-2016

I am attempting to split out different teams in our company radius authentication for several cisco and linux devices using NPS on server 2016.

I have added all IP ranges and single IPs to the Radius clients and can access them all with a ad user group membership fine. Now that I want to create a couple more AD groups and have each group only have access to a sub set of the devices, I am struggling with the regex required in the "client ipv4 address" field to include all devices per group.

The below works for 99% of devices the first group needs access to.
    192.168.1|2|10|11|12|20|21|22..+
I then want to grant it access to a single device at 10.0.0.99 (but no other devices in that range) and a few other single IPs eg 172.0.0.45, 172.0.0.46, 10.10.10.50, 10.10.10.52

The 192.168.x.x range works fine, but adding the additional IPs using a separator stops the entire string working, such as , or | or ^ before and $ after each set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using capturing groups.

```
(192\.168\.(1|2|10|11|12|20|21|22)\..+)|(10\.0\.0\.99)|(172\.0\.0\.45)|(172\.0\.0\.46)|(10\.10\.10\.50)|(10\.10\.10\.52)
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/XF4wry/2)

Your regex also has a few vulnerabilities in it, since you're not escaping the `.`'s.

In order to maximise your security, remember to backslash the `.`'s, unless they are being used as "wildcards" (which match anything.

It also needs to have `(` brackets `)` around any `|` pipes, or they'll be interpreted in a way that you probably don't want.

See the [Microsoft regex page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/nps/nps-crp-reg-expressions#examples-for-network-policy-attributes) for more info.